# "Unresolved Typeref-Token" with SDL_net and .NET

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, sdl

When compiling my project with Visual Studio 2010, C++ with .NET, Win8 64bit as a 32bit application, I get the following warning:

```
warning LNK4248: Unresolved Typeref-Token (01000012) for "_TCPsocket".
```

[TCPsocket](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.fcg/TCPsocket/) is a struct of the SDL_net library. MSDN says, [LNK4248](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h8027ys9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) means, the compiler can only find a forward declaration. SDL_net is linked correct, all other SDL_net functions I am using are working properly...

Answer (score 1):

You should surround the include of the SDL_net header files with

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "SDL_net.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

With this you will be sure that the header file will only generate native references.

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work for me :/
The warning just stays the same... what exactly does this #pragma do and whats the different between native and non-native references?